# How many bytes are transferred jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

How can I know how many bytes were transferred when I do something like :

```
Jsoup.connect(url).get()
```

or when I POST onto forms ? Can I have one instance in my application and know how many bytes were transferred in total ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither the class `Connection` you get with `connect(...)`, nor `Document` has a method to get the documents size. But possible you can use a workaround:

```
int bytes = Jsoup.connect(...).get().toString().length();
```

With get you download the the full document, hence it's size is amount of bytes transferred. For *POST* you have to go the same way.

> Can I have one instance in my application and know how many bytes were transferred in total ?

There are many ways: use a singleton or a method that downloads your website and counts the bytes.

```
public class Example
{
    private static long bytesTotal;


    private Example() { }


    public static Document loadDocument(String url) throws IOException
    {
        final Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        bytesTotal += doc.toString().length();

        return doc;
    }
}
```

**A far better solution:** Checkout [Jsoup git](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/) and write a counter yourself - and push it ;-) would be a nice extension.